# How do i make my GradientButton redraw in my iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uibutton

I have an app with a button in the bottom that i'm creating using a UIButton library, GradientButton (found here: http://code.google.com/p/iphonegradientbuttons/).

I can create buttons fine, but i cannot for the world figure out how to change the colour gradient of the created button after i've set the color once...

I tried, as an example, to change the gradient in my button's actionlistener with various tricks, for example (i'm setting it in viewdidload the first time):

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"buttonPressed;changing style");    
    [checkInCheckOutButton useAlertStyle];//build-in method in gradientbutton that sets colour
    [checkInCheckOutButton setNeedsDisplay];//added this when first didn't work.
}
```

Am i missing something here? If i change any other, built-in component, say a regular button's text and/or background, all works fine.

If there's something i'm not getting regarding how objects are repainted in objective c, i'm all ears...

EDIT: after suggestion, i tried to add some code to alter the color arrays of the button. Unfortunately that didn't work either:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender{

NSLog(@"buttonPressed;changing style");    
self.checkInCheckOutButton.normalGradientColors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor redColor], [UIColor blueColor], nil];
self.checkInCheckOutButton.highlightGradientColors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor greenColor], [UIColor whiteColor], nil];
[self.checkInCheckOutButton setNeedsDisplay];//tried with and without
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Add these lines to the begin of every `use...Style` method:

```
normalGradient = NULL;
highlightGradient = NULL;
```

and add `[self setNeedsDisplay];` at the end of these methods.

After these changes it works!

Answer (score 0):

depends on when/why you want to change it.

It looks like you can just use `normalGradientColors` and `highlightedGradientColors` to outright change the colors.

That...honestly seems like all you have to do. just change those properties...hand in an array of colors.

```
//This changes the colors for UIControlStateNormal
theButton.normalGradientColors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor redColor] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor blueColor] CGColor], nil];
//This changes the colors for UIControlStateHighlighted
theButton.HighlightedGradientColors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor redColor] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor blueColor] CGColor], nil];
```

EDIT: added cast to CGColor. If you are using ARC you will have to add the bridge tag instead of the 'simple' cast

```
(__bridge id)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. For me, it didn't work unfortunately. i edited my question to show what i did. *sob* :)

Comment: sorry about that, I was a bit hasty. I thought about casting but didn't mention it.

Comment: Hey mate, maaan it still doesnt work for me. What's intersting is that in my "viewdidload" i have [checkInCheckOutButton useAlertStyle]; so the button has that color, but i don't set the highlighted. So the *first* time i change the arrays, the highlighted gets set so that the button is different when i press it, but after that, nothing happens when i switch the arrays. Somehow, the change only occurs when it has not previously been set.... i'm puzzled! :)

Comment: if you lok at the implementation of useAlertStyle, they cast a cgcolor to id... what are you doing? could you post the code you wrote? what if you  do NOT call useAlertStyle